# handle decomposition of three sphere $S^3$

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, low-dimensional-topology

Prove by attaching a 0- handle(the three diemsnion disc $D^3$) to the empty set,then attaching a 3-handle to the boundary of $D^3$ result in the $S^3$.

I don't quite understand how the process really looks like, more precise how to attaching the 3-handle to the $D^3$? And why it's $S^3$?

Comment: You are not stating the question correctly: $S^3$ has many handle decompositions. Your question is, likely,  asking you to prove that attaching a 3-handle to 0-handle results in a manifold homeomorphic to $S^3$. Or, maybe, you are asked to prove that $S^3$ has a handle decomposition with only two handles (0-handle and 3-handle).

Comment: I was trying to prove that attaching a 3-handle to 0-handle results in a manifold homeomorphic to $S^3$.@Moishe Kohan

Comment: I know it's one-point compactification of $\Bbb{R}^3$, if we remove one point in the 3-handle, then $S^3$ will gradually diffeomorphic to the open threee disc hence also $\Bbb{R}^3$. But this does not really provide rigorous proof.

Comment: Do you already know the theorem (Alexander) that any orientation-preserving homeomorphism of $S^2$ is isotopic to the identity? Without such a result, you cannot prove the claim.

Comment: No I don't know this theorem, I found it here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/132690/360262. How can I use this theorem to prove the claim?

Comment: thank you I see, we can isotopic the identification  $\varphi$ for the 3 handle to the identity, then just change the inner and outer part of the shell (after removing one point in the three handle) in four dimension space,then glue the corresponding points 
via the identity identification gives the open three disc

Comment: Right..........

Comment: Hi @Moishe Kohan ,  the  theorem (Alexander) above is also useful in the construction of Heegaard diagram correct? Since given a Heegaard decomposition $(\Sigma_g,U_1,U_2)$ for some 3-manifold $M$, if we specifies  how to attaching those circle, what left is a ball, to attach the boundary $S^2$ the idenfication $\varphi$ isotopic to the indentity,therefore it contains no other information, after specifying those attaching circle?

Comment: Of course. You also need a version for maps of annuli and disks.

Comment: It can not use the Hopf theorem then.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: Never mind, I just mean that for the diffeomorphism on the sphere $S^n \to S^n$ the degree must be $+1/-1$, since orientation preserving, it must be $+1$, and $id$ map also has degree 1, therefore by hopf theorem they are homotopy, for  annuli and disks i'm not sure if there is some criterion of homotopy based on the degree of the map